# Windows not resolving DNS

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine which looses it's ability to resolve DNS after running a certain time (several weeks).

Network interface is configured to use my router as DNS server which does also work for any other device in my network. The router can be pinged and internet connection is existing as well. Changing the DNS server (e.g. to 8.8.8.8) doesn't change anything.

On the router I have a tcpdump for DNS requests running which shows that no packets on UDP port 53 are received from the server. Thus I think that the server is not even trying to reach the DNS server in the first place.

Restarting the machine resolves the issue, still it's annoying to do every time. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Try to run nslookup once the issue occurs to find out which DNS server are used by the server right now. I've faced it once and reconfiguring (including reinstalling networking drives) of the networking card helps me

Comment: As said the network is configured to use my router as DNS server and this is also the one nslookup supposingly sends the request to. Also as said before this request is not received on the router while routing is working as pings show.

Comment: Is IPv6 enabled on that machine? If yes, disable that. If no, it's 3rd party software (AV, Clientsecurity, Network-Security, ...)